# I want to call on number which have ending ,01#

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-phone-call

I am trying to call on a number which has an ending like `,01#`  and want to show on dial screen, I can't find any solution if anyone have solution for this type of issue please give and thanks in advance. I have tried this.

```
  String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber("1111111111,12#",  
  Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
  Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
  callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+formattedNumber));//change the number
  startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

comma is not allowed in dialpad, replace comma with plus sign or hash sign.

it will start work.

Comment: But when i dial this no comma is showing but # sign is not visible , i want that visible